# Two components with identical modifiers, yet the bevel modifiers have different results?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bevel

I have the top and bottom cover of an assault rifle model I'm building. Both sections have identical modifier settings, yet the bevel mod between the two look completely different.

Thoughts?
[image]
[image]

Comment: It must be unapplied scale of the object. In *Object Mode* Ctrl + A -> Scale

Comment: Nope... tried that... Its got to do with complex geometry. But I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: Oh yeah it is possible that some verts are too close together on one of the objects and it's limiting the distance.

Comment: I'll try check that quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that some of the vertices are too close, and the *Bevel* modifier is automatically limiting the offset amount.

The bevel will only be as big as it can be between the two closest vertices without overlapping.

[image]