# Fine cutouts with a wide bevel

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to model the following plate in blender:
[image]

I tried bending a plane to form the general shape of the plate, and then adding solidify, boolean cutouts and then bevel them.

At this point, whatever I do goes sideways really fast - the bevels overshoot or don't appear at all, the cutouts don't end up round, etc.

Here is an example of a simple attempt - I start off with a plane and a cutout (I have to bevel the cutter so that I have the round corners properly:

[image]

I then add solidify and bevel:

[image]

The bevel doesn't show, because clamp overlap is on... When I turn it off it either messes up the geometry, and the widest I can get it and still have it look reasonable is this:

[image]

Adding subdivision before the boolean and/or bevel doesn't help much either:

[image]

Can someone direct me, or help me understand what I'm doing wrong? Is my entire approach to the process wrong? Am I using the modifiers in a wrong way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well, the easiest answer is: do all booleans and then fix your topology before you try to apply subdiv or bevel to it... if you cut into mesh like that you will create a lot of ngons, you will need to remove them

Comment: I think the tool that cut those holes has a slight taper, which is why the top part of the round hole has a bigger radius than the bottom (inside) part.  I might try tapering the cylinder to form the slope between the top and bottom and not using a bevel at all.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234450/two-components-with-identical-modifiers-yet-the-bevel-modifiers-have-different/234635#234635

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach *without Booleans* is to model this plate from a subdivided plane and then add some modifiers. Lay the mesh over the reference image and remove the square faces where the holes should be:

[image: screenshot 1]

Then either extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>) and scale a support loop:

[image: extrude and scale]

**-or-** fill (<kbd>F</kbd>), inset (<kbd>I</kbd>) and remove the face. Later creates an edge with even width. On the outer edges of the plate you need to use *Extrude*:

[image: inset example]

For comparison, the left/bottom area has extruded/inset extra support loops, the right/top area has none and is a bit jagged:

[image: final model]

The round holes can be created with the *Mesh:LoopTools* add-on that ships with Blender (screenshot 1). The edges can be smoothed with the *Relax* operation of the *LoopTools*.

Comment: Good suggestion, way cleaner this way.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation, and the explanatory images! Not all heroes wear capes :-)
The solution is indeed far better than the boolean approach, and the relax feature + insets solve it perfectly IMO. Cheers!