# Why is my bevel modifier not working?

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I want to bevel my main cube like shape, but when I add a Bevel modifier nothing happens. I did already use a Boolean tool. Is that the reason my bevel modifier is not doing anything?

**EDIT**: I do get a small bevel when I set the Limit Method to none, but it doesn't make a difference if the amount, for example, is 0.1m or if it's 0.8m
I tried deleting all the booleans and corresponding cubes, but it doesn't make any difference.
The scale is also 1.0 everywhere.

These are the modifier settings:
[image]

Here is the file:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe it would help if you would show us at least the modifier panel with the settings of the modifiers...?

Comment: You can use virtually as many modifiers as you want. The issue is most likely your new bevel modifier is set in a way that produces no visible result. Hence, we need to see your modifier's settings.

Comment: Or share your file so that we can give a look

Comment: I added the file

Comment: I also added the modifier settings

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/234635/110840

Comment: How would I know if the vertices are too close together? I wouldn't think that's the case, but I can check. How would I change that?